# Use multi-dimensional PHP array in to create friendly URLS for each menu item in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, navigation

The MySQL navigation table uses id, parent_id, name to have an unlimited navigation depth. I am using a recursive function to create the multidimensional array, that works. What I have been trying for hours is to create a function that puts the path (/mainitem/subitem/subsubsitem/subsubsubitem/ etc in the menu_nl of the menu table:

[image: Description of table 'menu']

$q = "
    SELECT      m.id, m.parent_id,  m.menu_nl, parents.menu_nl AS 'parent'
    FROM        menu AS m
    LEFT JOIN   menu AS parents ON parents.id = m.parent_id
    ORDER BY    m.parent_id ASC, m.volgorde ASC";

$r = $dbcon->query($q);
$pages = $r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

```
function create_array(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {

    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {


            $children = create_array($elements, $element['id']);

            if ($children) {
                $element[$element['menu_nl']] = $children;
            }


            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

$tree = create_array($pages);

A var_export looks this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 34,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'menu_nl' => 'INTRODUCTION',
    'parent' => NULL,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 36,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'menu_nl' => 'TEAM',
    'parent' => NULL,
    'TEAM' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 133,
        'parent_id' => 36,
        'menu_nl' => 'Team member A',
        'parent' => 'TEAM',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 134,
        'parent_id' => 36,
        'menu_nl' => 'Team member B',
        'parent' => 'TEAM',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 50,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'menu_nl' => 'PRODUCTS',
    'parent' => NULL,
    'PRODUCTS' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 151,
        'parent_id' => 50,
        'menu_nl' => 'SUB PRODUCT A',
        'parent' => 'PRODUCTS',
        'SUB PRODUCT A' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 154,
            'parent_id' => 151,
            'menu_nl' => 'SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A',
            'parent' => 'SUB PRODUCT A',
            'SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'id' => 156,
                'parent_id' => 154,
                'menu_nl' => 'SUB OF SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A',
                'parent' => 'SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 152,
        'parent_id' => 50,
        'menu_nl' => 'SUB PRODUCT B',
        'parent' => 'PRODUCTS',
        'SUB PRODUCT B' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 155,
            'parent_id' => 152,
            'menu_nl' => 'SUB OF SUB PRODUCTB',
            'parent' => 'SUB PRODUCT B',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'id' => 153,
        'parent_id' => 50,
        'menu_nl' => 'SUB PRODUCT C',
        'parent' => 'PRODUCTS',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 40,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'menu_nl' => 'CONTACT',
    'parent' => NULL,
    'CONTACT' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 139,
        'parent_id' => 40,
        'menu_nl' => 'Contact form',
        'parent' => 'CONTACT',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 143,
        'parent_id' => 40,
        'menu_nl' => 'How to get there',
        'parent' => 'CONTACT',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I think this is still a little too abstract and broad. Can you at least provide some real data to play with? Try `var_export($array);` to get something tangible to post on here. And shouldn't `return $pad;` be `return $path;` in your function?

Comment: You are right Jeff, $pad is of course $path in the return. I've added a piece of the array, thanks

Comment: If you use `var_export` instead of `print_r` it makes it so that we can easily copy/paste functional code.

Comment: I hope this makes my code more clear, I want to do a much as possible with PHP and arrays and not with SQL queries. The function should create an update of the database after every edit or creation of a menu item, so the menu field can be used to find the page ID. That is the plan at least, if the menu fields are updated after a change I can also use the field to create a sitemap in XML format. Creating the sitemap is not the issue though.

Comment: you've provided your bad output, and while that's helpful, I was asking for you to please provide your input. `var_export($pages);` not `$tree` thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save the element's fullpath in the array as a concatenation of its parent's path with its own. Then pass that down as a parameter in your recursive function.

[live demo](https://3v4l.org/Eovh3)

[example repository](https://github.com/scratchers/stackoverflow.com-a-42125270-4233593)

```
<?php

// add $parentpath parameter
function create_array(array $elements, $parentId = 0, $parentpath = '') {

    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        // set the fullpath from parent concatenated to this menu_nl
        $element['fullpath'] = "$parentpath/$element[menu_nl]";

        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {

            // pass the fullpath down to its children
            $children = create_array($elements, $element['id'], $element['fullpath']);

            if ($children) {
                $element[$element['menu_nl']] = $children;
            }

            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

$pages = require 'pages.php';

print_r( create_array($pages) );
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 34
>             [parent_id] => 0
>             [menu_nl] => INTRODUCTION
>             [parent] => 
>             [fullpath] => /INTRODUCTION
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 36
>             [parent_id] => 0
>             [menu_nl] => TEAM
>             [parent] => 
>             [fullpath] => /TEAM
>             [TEAM] => Array
>                 (
>                     [0] => Array
>                         (
>                             [id] => 133
>                             [parent_id] => 36
>                             [menu_nl] => Team member A
>                             [parent] => TEAM
>                             [fullpath] => /TEAM/Team member A
>                         )
>
>                     [1] => Array
>                         (
>                             [id] => 134
>                             [parent_id] => 36
>                             [menu_nl] => Team member B
>                             [parent] => TEAM
>                             [fullpath] => /TEAM/Team member B
>                         )
>
>                 )
>
>         )
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 50
>             [parent_id] => 0
>             [menu_nl] => PRODUCTS
>             [parent] => 
>             [fullpath] => /PRODUCTS
>             [PRODUCTS] => Array
>                 (
>                     [0] => Array
>                         (
>                             [id] => 151
>                             [parent_id] => 50
>                             [menu_nl] => SUB PRODUCT A
>                             [parent] => PRODUCTS
>                             [fullpath] => /PRODUCTS/SUB PRODUCT A
>                             [SUB PRODUCT A] => Array
>                                 (
>                                     [0] => Array
>                                         (
>                                             [id] => 154
>                                             [parent_id] => 151
>                                             [menu_nl] => SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A
>                                             [parent] => SUB PRODUCT A
>                                             [fullpath] => /PRODUCTS/SUB PRODUCT A/SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A
>                                             [SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A] => Array
>                                                 (
>                                                     [0] => Array
>                                                         (
>                                                             [id] => 156
>                                                             [parent_id] => 154
>                                                             [menu_nl] => SUB OF SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A
>                                                             [parent] => SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A
>                                                             [fullpath] => /PRODUCTS/SUB PRODUCT A/SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A/SUB OF SUB OF SUB PRODUCT A
>                                                         )
>
>                                                 )
>
>                                         )
>
>                                 )
>
>                         )
>
>                     [1] => Array
>                         (
>                             [id] => 152
>                             [parent_id] => 50
>                             [menu_nl] => SUB PRODUCT B
>                             [parent] => PRODUCTS
>                             [fullpath] => /PRODUCTS/SUB PRODUCT B
>                             [SUB PRODUCT B] => Array
>                                 (
>                                     [0] => Array
>                                         (
>                                             [id] => 155
>                                             [parent_id] => 152
>                                             [menu_nl] => SUB OF SUB PRODUCTB
>                                             [parent] => SUB PRODUCT B
>                                             [fullpath] => /PRODUCTS/SUB PRODUCT B/SUB OF SUB PRODUCTB
>                                         )
>
>                                 )
>
>                         )
>
>                     [2] => Array
>                         (
>                             [id] => 153
>                             [parent_id] => 50
>                             [menu_nl] => SUB PRODUCT C
>                             [parent] => PRODUCTS
>                             [fullpath] => /PRODUCTS/SUB PRODUCT C
>                         )
>
>                 )
>
>         )
>
>     [3] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 40
>             [parent_id] => 0
>             [menu_nl] => CONTACT
>             [parent] => 
>             [fullpath] => /CONTACT
>             [CONTACT] => Array
>                 (
>                     [0] => Array
>                         (
>                             [id] => 139
>                             [parent_id] => 40
>                             [menu_nl] => Contact form
>                             [parent] => CONTACT
>                             [fullpath] => /CONTACT/Contact form
>                         )
>
>                     [1] => Array
>                         (
>                             [id] => 143
>                             [parent_id] => 40
>                             [menu_nl] => How to get there
>                             [parent] => CONTACT
>                             [fullpath] => /CONTACT/How to get there
>                         )
>
>                 )
>
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Comment: Jeff you provided me with the missing part, this will work just fine. Thanks! Recursion is difficult to get your head around, but is in this case the most efficient way to get things done, After flattening and looping I will have a perfect navigation table that can easily be modified for multi-lingual versions of a site. So thanks again!